# What are the differences between `ld1`/`st1` and `ldr`/`str`, `ldp`/`stp` instructions when operating on one or two vector registers?

Tags: assembly, arm, simd, arm64, neon

I am working on some ARM assembly code and I want to know the differences between ld1/st1 and ldr/str, ldp/stp instructions when operating on one or two vector registers. I know that ld1 has some limitations on the offset or post index range. Are there any other differences? I am especially interested in the performance differences.

I have read the ARM documentation for these instructions, but I am still confused. Can someone explain the differences in detail and give some examples of when to use each instruction?

Comment: `ld1/st1` allow you to select the lane (element).

Comment: As for performance, this is implementation-dependent.  For its own cores (Cortex, Neoverse, etc), ARM publishes a Software Optimization Guide showing cycle counts for every instruction, so you could refer to that.  For other manufacturers (e.g. Apple), they keep this proprietary; you may be able to find third-party empirical data, or gather your own.

Comment: I've been meaning, for my own benefit, to go through all the ARM64 ASIMD load/store instructions and write something up.  Maybe now is the time.

Comment: @NateEldredge Thank you for your comment,. I've checked the Guide for different Cortex cores. I found that they have the same latency and throughput under the conditions of the question.

However, I also found this statement in the [llvm documentation](https://llvm.org/docs/BigEndianNEON.html): “In strict alignment mode, LDR qX requires its address to be 128-bit aligned, whereas LD1 only requires it to be as aligned as the lane size. ”

This seems to imply that LD1 would generate more bus requests, but I did not find any mention of this in the ARM manuals. I am confused about this.

Comment: `LD1` only loads a single lane, it does not generate more requests. What would it do with the additional requests?

Comment: @Jester: It looks like that document is talking about the "LD1 (multiple structures)" form, which is really a different instruction with the same mnemonic.  It loads *all* the lanes of the destination register(s), from successive addresses in memory.

Comment: @ZzTux: I wouldn't expect the alignment thing to make a difference as to number of bus requests.  Since strict alignment checking is optional (and indeed rarely used), the chip has to be able to execute both instructions whether aligned or not, so I'd expect the number of bus accesses would depend only on whether the address actually *is* aligned, and that this would be the same for both instructions.

Comment: @ZzTux: Given the above note, maybe you should clarify whether your question is about the "single structure" or "multiple structures" form of the instruction.

Comment: The LLVM doc does however make the good point that LDR and LD1 (multiple structures) behave quite differently in big-endian mode.  Though that too is rarely used.